# (Python) automatically put an input

Tags: python, azure, input

I am using Microsoft Azure to create a virtual machine.
There is an Azure command line

```
az group delete --name myResourceGroup
```

, which, if I type it, returns

```
Are you sure you want to perform this operation? (y/n):
```

I want my Python script to automatically put "y" whenever it gets the question from the command line. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible in your case, you can add the --yes parameter in the command line to skip the confirmation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-delete

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is using the os module:

```
import os
os.system("y")
```

You can use this to automatically send in "y" right after you give `az group delete --name myResourceGroup`.
Cheers.